# Not able to delete shape objects from fabric canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I uploaded an image as background image, so that I am able to draw circle and rectangle on top of it. 
But, when I try to delete any shape, I am not able to do that.
I tried debugging and it just says Unexpected token ) on Delete 
I am just not able to figure out what exactly is the problem here.

```js
//-----------------------------Getting hold of Canvas----------------------------

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight * .75);
canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth * .75);
drawBackground();

//--------------------------Image Rendering--------------------------------------

function drawBackground() {
  fabric.Image.fromURL('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg', function(img) {
    img.scaleToWidth(window.innerWidth * .75);
    img.scaleToHeight(window.innerHeight * .75);
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(img);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
}

//------------------------Reset--------------------------------------------------

/*window.reset = function(){
   canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
   drawBackground();
}*/

//------------------------Rectangle----------------------------------------------

window.addRect = function() {
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    stroke: 'red',
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,.4)',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  });
  rect.hasRotatingPoint = false;
  canvas.add(rect);
}

//---------------------Circle----------------------------------------------------

window.addCircle = function() {
  var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    radius: 20,
    stroke: 'green',
    fill: 'transparent',
  });
  circle.hasRotatingPoint = false;
  canvas.add(circle);
}

//--------------------Delete Objects---------------------------------------------

window.delete = function() {
  canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js">
</script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>
<!--<button onClick="reset()">Reset</button> !-->
<button onClick="addCircle()">Circle</button>
<button onClick="addRect()">Box</button>
<button onClick="delete()">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete is a reserved word and cant be used as a function on the window object.

A helpful link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

You use delete as function inline right here:
    `<button onClick="delete()">Delete</button>`

Comment: Thank you so much!! it worked. I am marking this as my answer.

Comment: No problem @mili sharma

Comment: I am stuck again when I am trying to delete a group. So basically I created an arrow making rectangle and triangle as a group. When I try to delete it with the same function as above, it just deletes the triangle and the line remains on the canvas. I read about the canvas.getActiveGroup() method. But I guess its not supported anymore, as I am getting "canvas.getactivegroup is not a function" error. I tried whatever I could. Shall I create a different question thread for this issue?

Comment: I am sort of new to stack overflow but i would say that its safe to say that you can create a new question since it's about a the getActiveGroup method

Comment: Yes, I already did and got answer too. stackoverflow rocks. :)